# R: How does vectorized ifelse work in the context of multi-value yes/no parameters?

Tags: r

Gelman and Hill are explaining simulation in R. On page 139 they say:

52% of adults in the United States are women and 48% are men. The heights of the
men are approximately normally distributed with mean 69.1 inches and standard
deviation 2.9 inches; women with mean 63.7 and standard deviation 2.7.
Suppose we select 10 adults at random. What can we say about their average
height?

```
sex <- rbinom (10, 1, .52) R code
height <- ifelse (sex==0, rnorm (***10***, 69.1, 2.9), rnorm (***10***, 64.5, 2.7))     #"***"s added for emphasis.
avg.height <- mean (height)
print (avg.height)
```

I don't understand what the two 10's are doing in rnorm function.

sex is a 10-vector. if sex[1] is 0, ifelse selects ten values for height from normal distribution with mean 69.1 ..., if sex[2] is 1 ifelse selects 10 values for height from normal with mean 64.5, and so on, and only value of sex[10] will determine what will be eventually assigned to height.

Obviously my understanding is incorrect and it is picking the ten values from the right distribution. I changed mean of first normal distribution to 669.1 to understand how it is assigning value to height, and the code above is doing what it is supposed to do. I still do not understand what the two 10's are dong in rnorm functions. When I changed the two 10's to two 1's everything works as it should. 
Can someone please explain to me how ten values for height are assigned in the above code.

Comment: It's running `rnorm` under different parameters depending on the outcome of `sex == 0`.  `ifelse()` returns a vector the length of its first input (10), so the result needs to be length 10.

Comment: the result needs to be of length 10, but not the `yes` and `no` values. I think that's the confusion.

Comment: You can type `ifelse` just like that into the console to see its code. It boils down to `ans <- test; ans[test] <- yes[test]; ans[!test] <- no[!test]; return(ans)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a difference when defining the correct number of observations. That is because apparently the `ifelse` function first "completes" the data for both options, like a data.frame, then applies the if selection for every row. Since `sex` is a 10 element vector, so the 10s are necessary in the `rnorm` function for getting the right answer. You can see that substituting the 10s by 1s, passing one or ten element vector to `ifelse` and resetting the `seed` for every random generation. See below:

```
> set.seed(12345)
> sex <- rbinom (10, 1, .52) 
> 
> set.seed(12345)
> ifelse (sex[1]==0, rnorm (1, 69.1, 2.9), rnorm (1, 64.5, 2.7)) #correct
[1] 70.79803
> set.seed(12345)
> ifelse (sex[1]==0, rnorm (10, 69.1, 2.9), rnorm (10, 64.5, 2.7)) #almost true
[1] 70.79803
> set.seed(12345)
> ifelse (sex==0, rnorm (1, 69.1, 2.9), rnorm (1, 64.5, 2.7)) #wrong
 [1] 70.79803 70.79803 70.79803 70.79803 66.41556 66.41556 66.41556 66.41556 70.79803
[10] 70.79803
> set.seed(12345)
> ifelse (sex==0, rnorm (10, 69.1, 2.9), rnorm (10, 64.5, 2.7)) #correct
 [1] 70.79803 71.15745 68.78302 67.78486 62.47356 66.70563 62.10683 63.60474 68.27594
[10] 66.43397
> # is this what ifelse is doing?
> set.seed(12345)
> da=data.frame(sex, M=rnorm (10, 69.1, 2.9), W=rnorm (10, 64.5, 2.7))
> da$res <- apply(da,1,function(sx)ifelse(sx[1]==0,sx[2],sx[3]))
> da$res
 [1] 70.79803 71.15745 68.78302 67.78486 62.47356 66.70563 62.10683 63.60474 68.27594
[10] 66.43397
```

Comment: *deleted my previous answer to prevent confusion as I now think it was incorrect. @Robert's answer makes more sense to me.